# C++ read from textfile to doubles + value

Tags: c++, text, double, ifstream, getline

I'm trying to read a .txt file and save the contents to doubles in C++.
The .txt file is in the form: x (tab) 9 (tab) comments (newline)
What I need in C++ is double x=9;

```
//Read constants from file.
string name;
double value;
double a,b,c,d,th; //these are all stored in the file

ifstream fin("File.txt");
while (fin >>name>>value)
{
    getline(fin,name,value);

};
```

How to proceed? Thanks

Comment: You haven't articulated the actual problem you're facing. Do you mind explaining the issue please?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are consuming data for any other purpose but conversion. It can be done with AWK oneliner.

Answer (score 1):

You're not clearing the newline character after the last formatted extraction. `std::getline()` stops reading when it finds a newline so you should clear it out using `std::ws`:

```
while (std::getline(fin >> name >> value >> std::ws, name))
//                                          ^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: +1 How purposefully evil to combine stream extraction and `getline` :-)